¿Cómo extraer datos de un json por rangos de fecha con una clase diseñada en python?
La siguiente clase extrae los datos en un determinado rango de tiempo.
from datetime import date
import json

class DelimitedData:

    def oneMonth(self, keyDate, path, pathEnd):
        data = self.getData(path)
        fil = []
        for i in data:
            if(self.validDate(i, keyDate, 1)):
                fil.append(i)
        content = json.dumps(fil, sort_keys=True, indent=4)
        self.saveData(pathEnd, content)

    def quarter(self, keyDate, path, pathEnd):
        data = self.getData(path)
        fil = []
        for i in data:
            if(self.validDate(i, keyDate, 3)):
                fil.append(i)
        content = json.dumps(fil, sort_keys=True, indent=4)
        self.saveData(pathEnd, content)

    def semester(self, keyDate, path, pathEnd):
        data = self.getData(path)
        fil = []
        for i in data:
            if(self.validDate(i, keyDate, 6)):
                fil.append(i)
        content = json.dumps(fil, sort_keys=True, indent=4)
        self.saveData(pathEnd, content)

    def getData(self, path):
        f = open(path,"r")
        content = f.read()
        f.close()
        return json.loads(content)

    def saveData(self, path, content):
        f = open(path,"w")
        f.write(content)
        f.close()

    def validDate(self, registro, keyDate, monthInit):
        year = int(registro[keyDate][0:4])
        month = int(registro[keyDate][5:7])
        nowYear = int(date.today().year)
        nowMonth = int(date.today().month)

        checkMonth = nowMonth-monthInit
        if(checkMonth < 0):
            nowYear -= 1
            checkMonth += 12

        if(year == nowYear):
            if(month >= checkMonth):
                return True
            else:
                return False
        else:
            return False

Teniendo la siguiente estructura Json como ejemplo.
[
    {
        "artiId": "496",
        "artiNombre": "Uchuva",
        "cantidadTon": "1",
        "enviado": "None",
        "fechaCreacion": "None",
        "fechaMesIni": "2020-03-01 00:00:00-05:00",
        "fuenId": "70",
        "fuenNombre": "Barranquilla, Granabastos",
        "futiId": "794",
        "tmpAbasMesId": "None"
    },
    {
        "artiId": "407",
        "artiNombre": "Arracacha",
        "cantidadTon": "1",
        "enviado": "None",
        "fechaCreacion": "None",
        "fechaMesIni": "2020-03-01 00:00:00-05:00",
        "fuenId": "70",
        "fuenNombre": "Barranquilla, Granabastos",
        "futiId": "794",
        "tmpAbasMesId": "None"
    }
]

Demostración:
from delimitedData import DelimitedData

delimitaConsulta = DelimitedData()
delimitaConsulta.oneMonth("fechaMesIni", "./data/json/promedioAbasSipsaMesMadr.json", "./sample/json/oneMonth/oneMonth.json")
delimitaConsulta.quarter("fechaMesIni", "./data/json/promedioAbasSipsaMesMadr.json", "./sample/json/quarter/quarter.json")
delimitaConsulta.semester("fechaMesIni", "./data/json/promedioAbasSipsaMesMadr.json", "./sample/json/semester/semester.json")

Preguntas:
¿Cómo sería un método para extraer datos de hace un año?
¿Cómo sería un método para extraer datos de hace cinco años?
¿El código tiene fallas en su estructura?
¿Has encontrado alguna falla en su ejecución?
¿Hay una forma de hacer lo mismo pero de manera mas eficiente?
Cómo vamos con este asunto:
Dadas las sugerencias de Candid Moe, se adaptó el código y dio como resultado una ejecución más rápida y eficiente. Como el código ya lo estaba usando en un proyecto que estoy desarrollando y no quiero que se rompa, lo adapté para que se pueda usar de diferentes formas y haya retrocompatibilidad, habiendo 3 formas de usarlo, la antigua y dos formas alternas mas eficientes en su ejecución, pero con los mismos resultados.
El código queda así por el momento:
from datetime import date
import json

class DelimitedData:

    def __init__(self, path:str="")->None:
        self.data = []
        self.path = ""
        if(path != ""):
            self.getData(path)

    def getData(self, path:str="")->None:
        if(path != ""):
            self.path = path
            f = open(self.path,"r")
            content = f.read()
            f.close()
            self.data = json.loads(content)

    def oneMonth(self, keyDate:str="", path:str="", pathEnd:str="")->None:
        if(path != ""):
            self.path = path
            self.getData(path)
        res = self.period(keyDate, 1)
        content = json.dumps(res, sort_keys=True, indent=4)
        self.saveData(pathEnd, content)

    def quarter(self, keyDate:str="", path:str="", pathEnd:str="")->None:
        if(path != ""):
            self.path = path
            self.getData(path)
        res = self.period(keyDate, 3)
        content = json.dumps(res, sort_keys=True, indent=4)
        self.saveData(pathEnd, content)

    def semester(self, keyDate:str="", path:str="", pathEnd:str="")->None:
        if(path != ""):
            self.path = path
            self.getData(path)
        res = self.period(keyDate, 6)
        content = json.dumps(res, sort_keys=True, indent=4)
        self.saveData(pathEnd, content)

    def period(self, keyDate:str="", meses:int=0)->object:
        data = self.data
        res = []
        for i in data:
            if self.validDate(i, keyDate, meses):
                res.append(i)
        return res
    
    def validDate(self, registro:object={}, keyDate:str="", monthInit:int=0)->bool:
        year = int(registro[keyDate][0:4])
        month = int(registro[keyDate][5:7])
        nowYear = int(date.today().year)
        nowMonth = int(date.today().month)

        checkMonth = nowMonth - monthInit
        if (checkMonth < 0):
            nowYear -= 1
            checkMonth += 12

        if (year == nowYear):
            if (month >= checkMonth):
                return True
            else:
                return False
        else:
            return False

    def saveData(self, path:str="", content:str="")->None:
        f = open(path,"w")
        f.write(content)
        f.close()



Las tres formas de usarlo serían:
La primera (antigua)
delimitaConsulta = DelimitedData()
delimitaConsulta.oneMonth("fechaMesIni", "./data/json/promedioAbasSipsaMesMadr.json", "./sample/json/oneMonth/oneMonth.json")
delimitaConsulta.quarter("fechaMesIni", "./data/json/promedioAbasSipsaMesMadr.json", "./sample/json/quarter/quarter.json")
delimitaConsulta.semester("fechaMesIni", "./data/json/promedioAbasSipsaMesMadr.json", "./sample/json/semester/semester.json")

La segunda
delimitedData = DelimitedData()
delimitedData.getData("./data/json/promedioAbasSipsaMesMadr.json")
delimitedData.oneMonth("fechaMesIni", pathEnd="./sample/json/oneMonth/oneMonthN2.json")

La tercera
delimitedData = DelimitedData("./data/json/promedioAbasSipsaMesMadr.json")
delimitedData.oneMonth("fechaMesIni", pathEnd="./sample/json/oneMonth/oneMonthN1.json")

Preguntas pendientes:
¿Cómo sería un método para extraer datos de hace un año?
¿Cómo sería un método para extraer datos de hace cinco años?
¿Has encontrado alguna falla en su ejecución?
Fuente:
Código original y datos para hacer pruebas:
https://github.com/oigonzalezp2024/delimitedData

Está mal modelado. Tienes una clase sin ningún atributo. En el fondo, es un grupo de funciones sin relación entre sí, que reciben toda la información vía parámetro.

No está muy "orientado al objeto" el código que muestras. Lo refactorize para que sea más "OO":
from datetime import date
import json


class DelimitedData:

    def __init__(self, path):
        self.path = path
        f = open(path, "r")
        content = f.read()
        f.close()
        self.registro = json.loads(content)

    def period(self, keyDate, meses, pathEnd):
        data = self.registro
        fil = []
        for i in data:
            if self.validDate(i, keyDate, meses):
                fil.append(i)
        content = json.dumps(fil, sort_keys=True, indent=4)

        f = open(pathEnd, "w")
        f.write(content)
        f.close()

    def oneMonth(self, keyDate, pathEnd):
        self.period(keyDate, 1, pathEnd)

    def quarter(self, keyDate, pathEnd):
        self.period(keyDate, 3, pathEnd)

    def semester(self, keyDate, pathEnd):
        self.period(keyDate, 6, pathEnd)


    def validDate(self, registro, keyDate, monthInit):
        year = int(registro[keyDate][0:4])
        month = int(registro[keyDate][5:7])
        nowYear = int(date.today().year)
        nowMonth = int(date.today().month)

        checkMonth = nowMonth - monthInit
        if (checkMonth < 0):
            nowYear -= 1
            checkMonth += 12

        if (year == nowYear):
            if (month >= checkMonth):
                return True
            else:
                return False
        else:
            return False
a = DelimitedData("/home/candid/data.txt")
a.oneMonth("fechaMesIni", "/home/candid/data2.txt")


Candid Moe tus mejoras al código funciona bien, dan los mismos resultados. Aunque prefiero que las acciones de leer, guardar y filtrar archivos estén en métodos aparte, para que cada método haga una sola cosa. Faltarían los métodos que permitan consultar la data por periodos de años.
